# How to override the from address in django email (sent through Gmail)

Tags: django, gmail

In my settings.py, I have this values:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'user@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'pass'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Then in my views, I am getting an email address from my models like for example:

```
#models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    email_address = models.EmailField()
```

Let's assume that the `email_address` in the `Profile` model is `sample@gmail.com`

```
#views
def send_email(request,profile_id):
   profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=profile_id)
   email = profile.email_address
```

so when i will send a mail,

```
send_mail('subject', 'content', email, ['example1@example.com'])
```

When the email was already sent, the sender_email is still user@gmail.com. Can someone teach me how to overwrite this email address? Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

The [`DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#default-from-email) setting is just that, the default. Django uses this in places where email is sent automatically (such as error reports to `ADMINS`). When you call the `send_mail` method directly, you must provide the `from_email` parameter. Even if you *wanted* the `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`, you would have to import it from `django.conf.settings` and then pass it in.

My best guess is that Gmail is actually the culprit here. To the best of my knowledge, Gmail does not let you specify a custom sender because too many people *already* try to use Gmail to send out spam, and they want to discourage that practice.

Basically, when your email goes through the Gmail outgoing mail servers, it's disregarding the custom headers you sent and sending it from your actual Gmail account user. You might be able to get around this by adding the custom from email you want to use as a valid sender in Gmail's settings. Go to Settings and then the "Accounts and Import" tab. Find the section entitled, "Send mail as" and click the "Add another email address you own" link. You can add a new email account you want to send from there, and it will make you confirm the address via email (so it needs to be a valid address that can receive email).

Comment: uhmmmmm, chris, about what you said, can you give me some example? and btw, the email that im using is valid. :D

Comment: Example of what? It's not about whether the email address you want to send from is valid or not; it's about whether it's setup in your Gmail account as an allowed sender. If it's not, Gmail will not let you use it as a sender.

Answer (score 1):

first you need to remove EMAIL_HOST_USER & EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD in your setting.py and use auth_user and auth_password

auth_user:: If EMAIL_HOST_USER has not been specified, or you want to override it, this username will be used to authenticate to the SMTP server.

auth_password:: If EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD  has not been specified, this password will be used to authenticate to the SMTP server.

```
mail.send_mail(
        subject='here your subject',
        message='message',
        from_email='fromepython@gmail.com',
        recipient_list=[to_email],
        auth_user = 'fromepython@gmail.com',
        auth_password = 'password',
        fail_silently=True,

)
```

Answer (score 0):

David, are you sure your email is coming across in your example?

From the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/
from_email: The sender's address. Both fred@example.com and Fred  forms are legal. If omitted, the DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL setting is used.

Furthermore: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#django.core.mail.send_mail
Your usage looks correct:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Over riding may not be the issue.  Your email may just be coming across blank?

Hope that helps.

Comment: yeah. even though im using the profile's email, when sent, the email_user is overwriting it. so i want to happen is the profile's email will be the sender_email

Comment: uhmmmmm, you said that email my just be coming across blank, its not. I have an email address inputed and it is valid.

Comment: Yes, but is it blank at this point in the code:  send_mail('subject', 'content', email, ['example1@example.com']) ?  can you send that email object as the content to see if it is coming through?

Comment: Let's assume that the email_address in the Profile model is sample@gmail.com. So in the views as shown in the above, you can see that the email in send_mail does  have value.