# Python Django Email

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-email

Good day, I have a Django app that sends emails. I used a google app password for my `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD`, it works perfectly fine, but the `from_email` always set to my email which I used to create the app password instead of the email it gets from the form.
How can I fix this, please?

**UPDATE**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.mail import send_mail


def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST["name"]
        email = request.POST["email"]
        phone = request.POST["phone"]
        message = request.POST["message"]

        msg = "Email: " + email + "\n" + message + "\nPhone Number: " + phone

        send_mail(
            name + " Sent Us A Message",
            msg,
            email,
            ["myemail@gmail.com"],
        )

        return render(request, "index.html", {"name": name})
    else:
        return render(request, "index.html", {})
```

Comment: Can you show code used to send email?

Comment: @Jarad I've updated the question

Comment: Since you are using gmail as your smtp server, you specify this under EMAIL_HOST in settings, google won't allow you to use a custom from_email for security reasons. The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418905/how-to-override-the-from-address-in-django-email-sent-through-gmail) explains it better. You can achieve what you are looking for using something like sendgrid or zoho. They also have good documentation on how to send email with django. cheers.

Comment: i tried using sendgrid but it keeps returning this error `You will not be able to send email through SendGrid until you provide more information. Please contact Support to answer a few more questions.` and `You are not authorized to access SendGrid, please contact Support.`