# Send email using Django and Gmail backend

Tags: python, django, email, gmail, gmail-api

I'm struggling sending emails with a custom domain using Gmail backend.

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ["EMAIL_HOST_USER"]
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ["EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD"]
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

```py
email = EmailMessage(
    subject,
    content,
    "myaccount@mydomain.com",
    [customer.email]
)
email.send()
```

I've created a Google account with the custom domain and generated an app password, but when using custom domain for `EMAIL_HOST_USER`, I get `(535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials')`:

```py
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ["EMAIL_HOST_USER"] # myaccount@mydomain.com
```

Then I tried with a Google account using a gmail.com domain, and this time it works:

```py
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ["EMAIL_HOST_USER"] # myaccount@gmail.com
```

So I need the sender's mail to be different than `myaccount@gmail.com`.
I've tried to add a secondary mail address in Google, and used `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "myaccount@mydomain.com"` but it doesn't seem to change anything.

I've also tried the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69390221/14321226), same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Follow These Steps

Set Up a Gmail Account App Password
In order for Django to be able to send e-mail through Gmail and comply with Gmail's sending policies, you'll need to set up less secure app access and create an app password.

If you don’t set up less secure app access, you’ll get a SMTPAuthenticationError when you try to send emails.

1. Navigate to myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps and turn on the less
   secure app's options.
2. Enable 2-factor authentication. This is required in order to use
   less secure apps.
3. Navigate to myaccount.google.com/security and scroll down to the
   "Signing Into Google" section. Click on "App Passwords."
4. You'll be asked to enter your personal Gmail account password. Next,
   click on "Select App" and input a name for your Django app. Use the
   same name that you gave to your app in the terminal
   (DjangoEmailServer.) Click "Generate."
5. Now you can copy the generated app password into the
   EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD value in your settings.py file.

   from django.core.mail import send_mail
   from django.conf import settings

   ```
   send(subject, message, recipients):
       send_mail(
               subject=subject,
               message=message,
               from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
               recipient_list=recipients)
   ```

`

Comment: As you said, Google does not support Less Secure App access anymore, so why telling me to turn on the less secure app's options? The page displays "This setting is not available for your account."
By the way, I've already tried the "from_email" param, that doesn't do anything. The sender's email is still the gmail one.

Comment: if you are using window, then note sendmail dose not work easliy you need write your function for it

Comment: It does work, the issue is that even with "from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER", the mail I receive is still sent by the Gmail address.